# Return 0 if there is no row available

Tags: sql

I have below Query

```
select rowid,ConnectionStatus,count(*) Count
from NAIL_CONN
where name like "WorkflowStatusHandlingMDBBeanEJB%"
group by ConnectionStatus
```

which returns me value like

```
rowed  ConnectionStatus Count

8      Connected    1
14      re-connecting   3
```

From this Query the possibility of ConnectionStatus returning are "re-connecting,disconnected and Connected"

I want it to return 0 when no row matches above criteria

example:

```
rowed  ConnectionStatus Count

8      Connected    1
14      re-connecting   3
10     disconnected     0
```

Pls ignore the rowed as it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. `"ConnectionStatus"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'WorkflowStatusHandlingMDBBeanEJB%'`.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the `SELECT` list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." I.e. in your case you should do `GROUP BY rowid, ConnectionStatus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all rows in your query, yet only count the matching ones.

```
select rowid,ConnectionStatus,
count(case when name like "WorkflowStatusHandlingMDBBeanEJB%" then 1 end) Count
from NAIL_CONN
group by ConnectionStatus
```

Another more efficient mechanism would be to left outer join a distinct list of ConnectionStatus with your original query.

Comment: yep, and to ensure that you can get all the ConnectionStatus i suggest to create a dim table to store it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a mapping table for this and what is the rowid for? if it doesn't mean anything to you just don't select it. and please mark the dbms you are using

via create table:

```
  create table ConnectionStatus (rowid int,ConnectionStatus varchar(20))
  insert into ConnectionStatus(rowid,ConnectionStatus)values(8,'Connected');
  insert into ConnectionStatus(rowid,ConnectionStatus)values(14,'re-connecting');
  insert into ConnectionStatus(rowid,ConnectionStatus)values(10,'disconnected ');
```

then just left join and case when is ok

```
    select nail.rowid,nail.ConnectionStatus,
           case when nail.rowid is null then 0 else nail.Count end as Count
    from ConnectionStatus conn
    left join 
      (select rowid,ConnectionStatus,count(1) Count
      from NAIL_CONN
      where name like "WorkflowStatusHandlingMDBBeanEJB%"
      group by ConnectionStatus) nail
    on nail.ConnectionStatus= conn.ConnectionStatus
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answering. I wont be able to create the table here as the application from where I am fetching the data has only readonly access.I just wish to read the table.